# Kubeflow fails to deploy using both CLI and Console

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I deleted my KF cluster last night to create a new one (using kubectl cluster command not Kfctl delete), and then when I tied to create a new one, it fails, it does not work with CLI not Console. I found other people have run into this issue before, for example ([here](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/4670) and [here](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/2347))

"However, as I said even with CLI my deployment fails, the error from console is:
ailed to apply:  (kubeflow.error): Code 500 with message: coordinator Apply failed for gcp:  (kubeflow.error): Code 500 with message: gcp apply could not update deployment manager Error could not update storage-kubeflow.yaml; Insert deployment error: googleapi: Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
More details:
Reason: insufficientPermissions, Message: Insufficient Permission"

and the error I get from Console is: 
"Please enable APIs for your project and try again
Please enable cloud resource manager API: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/ and iam API: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/iam.googleapis.com/"

Note that this error is wrong, all the apis are active already. I'm quite sure this is a bug of KF but not sure how to find a workaround, any thoughts?

With CLI, I'm using my own account which has "owner" privileges.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an issue with IAM and the installation of Kubeflow, a 3rd party product that itself is not supported by us; nevertheless I went ahead and dig some information about this Machine Learning product.

The main issues (and although it seems you already cover permissions) are permissions, number of projects and some fine grained points.

I was checking and found out the following things that may help

a) Troubleshooting Kubeflow [1](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/troubleshooting-gke/)

b)  Deploying Kubeflow in GKE[[2]](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/deploy/)

c) Kubleflow auto deployer for GKE[[3]](https://deploy.kubeflow.cloud/#/)

There are also some discussion about a mismatch permissions setting in Kubeflow that may be worth reading [[4]](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/3003)

Finally there is a group that, also on a best-effort basis due the nature of Kubeflow:"google-kubeflow-support@google.com" that may come in handy.

I trust this information will be useful for you to solve your issue